# Hibernate 5.2.17: ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an Oracle 18.4.0 XE database that I'm trying to access from JPA 2.1, implemented by Hibernate 5.2.17.

I have a `ManyToMany` connection between 2 entities:

```java
public class PermissionEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3862680194592486778L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String permission;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<RoleEntity> roles;
}
```

```java
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8037069621015090165L;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<PermissionEntity> permissions;
}
```

When trying to run the Spring Data JPA request on PermissionRepository: `findAllByPermission(Iterable<String> permissions)`, I get the following exception:

```
Error : 1797, Position : 140, Sql = select permission0_.id as id1_0_, permission0_.permission as permission2_0_ from PermissionEntity permission0_ where permission0_.permission=(:1  , :2 ), OriginalSql = select permission0_.id as id1_0_, permission0_.permission as permission2_0_ from PermissionEntity permission0_ where permission0_.permission=(? , ?), Error Msg = ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are telling the Spring Data Jpa engine to search for `Permission` where permission is equal to the list. It should use the **IN** operator so your method name should be:

```
findAByPermissionIn(Iterable<String> permissions)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'in' keyword: `findAllByPermissionIn(Iterable<String> permissions)`.

This would produce a query like this: `where permission0_.permission IN (:permissions)`.